# Деплой релиза MAVEN в Nexus

Tags: java, maven, jar, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Как разобраться с выпуском релиза? Запуск выпуска делаю командой:

```
-B release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"
```

В `pom` файле репозитарии есть:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-release</id>
        <url>http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Всё проходит успешно, но артефакт не деплоится в релизный репозитарий, просто нет этого этапа.

Да, когда делается snapshot деплой отлично отрабатывает. Когда собирается релиз деплоится в snapshot отличнл.

```
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ jar ---
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 3.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7.jar (17 KB at 180.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7.pom
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7.pom (3 KB at 60.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/maven-metadata.xml (373 B at 11.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml (257 B at 8.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 20.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/maven-metadata.xml (373 B at 7.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml (257 B at 4.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7-sources.jar (13 KB at 271.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 20.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 6.625 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-13T14:35:28+03:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 30M/414M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cleaning up after release...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.725 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-13T14:35:29+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/204M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Весь Лог. запускался -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true", т.к. проблема с формированием javadoc

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building automation-maven-plugin Maven Mojo 2.3.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'run-preparation-goals'
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building automation-maven-plugin Maven Mojo 2.3.2
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Deleting D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\src\main\resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 8 source files to D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\classes
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to read mojo metadata.
[INFO] [INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
[INFO] [INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 4 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] [INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] [INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] [INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
[INFO] [INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java-annotations found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\src\test\resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:addPluginArtifactMetadata (default-addPluginArtifactMetadata) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 54.918 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-13T16:52:06+03:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 20M/118M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
[INFO] Working directory: d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin
[INFO] Tagging release with the label automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git tag -F C:\TEMP\maven-scm-733806283.commit automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push http://IP:PORT/scm/iibs/automation-maven-plugin.git automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git ls-files"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin
[INFO] Transforming 'automation-maven-plugin Maven Mojo'...
[INFO] Not removing release POMs
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
[INFO] Working directory: d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin
[INFO] Release preparation complete.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:perform (default-cli) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git clone --branch automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2 http://IP:PORT/scm/iibs/automation-maven-plugin.git d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout"
[INFO] Working directory: d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git ls-remote http://IP:PORT/scm/iibs/automation-maven-plugin.git"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\TEMP
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git fetch http://IP:PORT/scm/iibs/automation-maven-plugin.git"
[INFO] Working directory: d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git checkout automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2"
[INFO] Working directory: d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git ls-files"
[INFO] Working directory: d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout
[INFO] Invoking perform goals in directory d:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing goals 'deploy'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for ru.rsb.esb.mvn:automation-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.3.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing.
[INFO] [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing.
[INFO] [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing.
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building automation-maven-plugin Maven Mojo 2.3.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout\src\main\resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 8 source files to D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout\target\classes
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to read mojo metadata.
[INFO] [INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
[INFO] [INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 4 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] [INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] [INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] [INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
[INFO] [INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java-annotations found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout\src\test\resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout\target\automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:addPluginArtifactMetadata (default-addPluginArtifactMetadata) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ automation-maven-plugin >>>
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ automation-maven-plugin <<<
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout\target\automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Skipping javadoc generation
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout\target\automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\CI\.m2\ru\rsb\esb\mvn\automation-maven-plugin\2.3.2-SNAPSHOT\automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Installing D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout\pom.xml to C:\CI\.m2\ru\rsb\esb\mvn\automation-maven-plugin\2.3.2-SNAPSHOT\automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] [INFO] Installing D:\Work\GIT\automation-maven-plugin\target\checkout\target\automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to C:\CI\.m2\ru\rsb\esb\mvn\automation-maven-plugin\2.3.2-SNAPSHOT\automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ automation-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO]               
[INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 2.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-20180213.135310-8.jar
[INFO]            
[INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-20180213.135310-8.jar (17 KB at 257.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-20180213.135310-8.pom
[INFO]          
[INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-20180213.135310-8.pom (3 KB at 76.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml  
[INFO]             
[INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (373 B at 11.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml
[INFO]             
[INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml (257 B at 10.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml  
[INFO]               
[INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 44.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml 
[INFO]             
[INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (373 B at 15.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml 
[INFO]             
[INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml (257 B at 12.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-20180213.135310-8-sources.jar 
[INFO]            
[INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/automation-maven-plugin-2.3.2-20180213.135310-8-sources.jar (13 KB at 411.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] 1001/1001 B   
[INFO]               
[INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../automation-maven-plugin/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 33.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 34.074 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-13T16:53:11+03:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 30M/409M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cleaning up after release...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:04 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-13T16:53:11+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Да, когда делается snapshot деплой отлично отрабатывает. Когда собирается релиз деплоится в snapshot отличнл.

```
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ jar ---
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 3.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7.jar (17 KB at 180.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7.pom
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7.pom (3 KB at 60.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/maven-metadata.xml (373 B at 11.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml (257 B at 8.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 20.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/maven-metadata.xml (373 B at 7.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../maven-metadata.xml (257 B at 4.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/jar-2.3.2-20180213.113528-7-sources.jar (13 KB at 271.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded: http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/../../../../jar/2.3.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 20.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 6.625 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-13T14:35:28+03:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 30M/414M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cleaning up after release...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.725 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-13T14:35:29+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/204M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: стандартная команда `deploy` отрабатывает?

Comment: Да, когда делается snapshot деплой отлично отрабатывает. Когда собирается релиз деплоится в snapshot отличнл.

Comment: попробуй выполнить `release:perform` без опций, и приложи лог.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Был использован плагин maven-release-plugin версии 2.3.2. При использовании версии 2.5.3 такой проблемы не возникает.